# how to capture the reaction of an emoji in a message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

when a message receives a reaction or emoji, I want to save the letter "y" in `Wish`.
I need to use `emoji` in `client.on("message", (message)`, not another, the next error is
`ReferenceError: emoji is not defined`
but i have no idea how to solve it

```
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js-selfbot");
const client = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS],
});

let token = "";

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ok!');
 });

 let ListWish = ["❤","",""];
 let Wish;

client.on("message", (message) => {
if(ListWish.includes(emoji.name)){
    Wish = 'y';
}

if(message.embeds.length >= 0) 
// Check if the Message has embed or not
      {
        let embed = message.embeds
        for(let i = 0; i < embed.length; i++)
        {
          if (!embed[i] || !embed[i].description) return;
          // check each embed if it has description or not, if it doesnt then do nothing
          {
            if(Wish === 'y'){
            message.channel.send("Have emoji heart")
            }
          }
        }
      }
});  
client.login(token);
```

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it solved your problem & to also let others know the question is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Message.awaitReactions()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions) method to listen for reactions on a certain message without the need of using `client.on('event')`.

The documentation already contains code that easily summarizes how to use it, so I won't write any code here.

**Edit:** I almost forgot to add this, I am pretty sure you can pass in a callback after the options, so there is no need to use `.then()`.